# chrome's file input element, full path retrieval and command lines

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, file-upload, command-line

Do **YOU** know how to retrieve a ***full*** file path from chrome's file input element?

The HTML:

```
<img id="person" src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/330/9/e/profile_icon_by_art311-d33mwsf.png" />
<input id="file" type="file" style="display:none" />
```

The jQuery:

```
$('#person').click(function(){
    $('#file').click()
});

$('#file').change(function(){
    person.src = this.value;
});
```

The Problem:

When the image is clicked and file is selected, the input in IE shows the full path to the file, `c:/media/me.png`, and this value is stored as `file.value`. Yet the input in chrome shows only the file name, `me.png`, and it's value and the image's `src` attribute reads `C:\fakepath\me.png`???

I have tried adding:

```
--disable-web-security
```

and/or

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

to my chrome shortcut **Target** and in **cmd.exe** without success???

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Leaving a comment here because I want to know the answer too. I have exactly the same problem. I have tried almost everything. I am starting to think it is impossible in Chrome.

Comment: @Chris cheers for the support dude, have left it open for answers but just seems to be a chrome security feature, haven't found a work-round as of yet, but still looking...

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution to my problem, I will post it here maybe it will help you too. It is almost impossible to get the absolute path in Chrome, however there is a temporary path you can use to access the file. To get the temporary file your code will look something like this:

```
$('#file').change(function(e){
    person.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/upcxxvay/1/

I hope this helps you like it helped me :)

Comment: cheers chris, but i use `URL.createObjectURL` anyway, i was just hoping there was a way to display the full path!